# Save result as insert in a file Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I want to save as insert into a file the result of a set of selects (more than 50). I know that I have the possibility to run the select and than export dataset, but that isn't easy for 50+ selects.

I tried with spool:

```
spool D:\work\selects.sql
select * from names; 
select * from address;
select * from country;
spool off;
```

The problem is that in my file the results aren't saved as insert. I am using Toad.

What can I do?

Comment: Take a look if there is a  Tools->export->export wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to spool on TOAD. Just run the query and right click on data set, then select export data set. Below link might be helpful.

https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/b/weblog/archive/2013/03/28/copying-database-data-to-microsoft-excel-via-toad

You may use below code to generate .xls from sqlplus. write all of your sql in a single file and save it as .sql file. then use sqlplus plus to execute the file.

> sqlplus / as sysdba @/u01/oracle/query.sql

```
set pages 20000
set lines 9999
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set termout off
set echo off
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SET NUM 24
SPOOL /u01/oracle/output.xls

prompt Test query 1;
select * from test1;

prompt Test query 2;
select * from test3;

........... ........... ........

SPOOL OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
```

Comment: Ok, but I have 50+ selects from different tables. I need an automatic way to somehow save the results as insert statements. Can I do that in Toad?

Comment: well in that case you need sqlplus. i am editing my ans and posting a code instead.